# How to get HTML for ASP.NET webrequest

Tags: asp.net, curl, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I want to get the source code of [this page](https://betorder.com/Sports.html).

```
string adres = "https://betorder.com/Sports.html";
    WebRequest gelenIstek = HttpWebRequest.Create(adres);
    WebResponse gelenCevap;
    using (gelenCevap = gelenIstek.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader donenDeger = new StreamReader(gelenCevap.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string gelenBilgi = donenDeger.ReadToEnd();
            string gonder = gelenBilgi;
            div.InnerHtml = gonder;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `http` schema to make a request and add the html to some div, like below:

**ASPX page**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlHtml"></asp:Panel>
</form>
```

**Your code-behind**:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        var adres = "http://betorder.com/Sports.html";
        var gelenIstek = HttpWebRequest.Create(adres);
        WebResponse gelenCevap;
        using (gelenCevap = gelenIstek.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var donenDeger = new StreamReader(gelenCevap.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var response = donenDeger.ReadToEnd();
                var divcontrol = new HtmlGenericControl
                {
                    TagName = "div", 
                    InnerHtml = response
                };
                pnlHtml.Controls.Add(divcontrol);
            }
        }
    }
```